# Can we assign a class field to default or optional parameter of method in same class (in C#)?

Tags: c#

I wanted to have a class as follows :

```
public static class Class
{
  static string Name { get; set; }

  public static void Method(string Name=Class.Name, string Type="default")
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Name={0}",Name);
  }
}
```

But default parameters must be compile time parameters. So any ideas how to achieve it?

Comment: It must be a constant at compile time

Comment: Since it's a private property, I added a method to class in order to set `Name` but this method should be called every time there's change in `Name` value

`public static class Class
{
  static string Name { get; set; }
  
  public static void SetName(string Name){ Class.Name=Name; }

  public static void Method(string Type="default"){ Console.WriteLine("Name={0}",Name); }
}`

Answer (score 2):

You should not be able to, unless the field in question is a `const`. And in your example, it is not even a field but a property.

Further reading would be helpful because there are cases where a constant is not a constant, i.e., decimal constants. See Jon Skeet's blog [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/22/when-is-a-constant-not-a-constant-when-its-a-decimal/).

Edit: Since you can't have `const`s, you'll need to resort to method overloading and the method with lesser number of parameters will call the one with larger number of parameters and provide the value for extra parameters.

Comment: It's value will be changing. So can't make it `const` :(

Comment: Then you can't have defaulted parameters either. Switch to overloading.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as far as I know. Have you considered using constants? the example below will compile.

```
public static class Class
{
    public const string Name = "Some name";
    public static void Method(string Name = Name, string Type = "default")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name={0}", Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use overloaded methods where one overload method will call the other one with the `Class.Name` value, when the argument is missing. It might look like this:

```
public static class Class
{
    static string Name { get; set; }

    public static void Method(string name, string type)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name={0}, type={1}", name, type);
    }

    public static void Method(string type) {
        Method(Class.Name, type);
    }

    public static void Method() {
        Method("default"); // the type
    }
}
```

When you have the following test code:

```
Class.Name = "Some default name";
Method();
Method("onlyType");
Method("withName", "andType");
```

you will get the following output:

```
Name=Some default name, type=default
Name=Some default name, type=onlyType
Name=withName, type=andType
```